# Error compiling for unit test using google toolbox for mac

Tags: iphone, xcode, unit-testing, ios, google-toolbox-for-mac

Hi my application runs fine but when I try to run the unit tests I am getting this error...

```
2010-10-19 00:27:49.919 AssignmentUnitTest[27988:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

Irony is I have searched the whole project & I dont have any similar line of code that uses `**[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]**`

I have pretty much wasted half of my day on it without any success.

I am using coredata in the project & below is the screen shot with stack trace.

Can anyone please guide me to the right direction.

Thanks 
[image: screen shot]

**EDIt : ** The solution to this problem is to add not only the .xcdatamodel file but the root file .xcdatamodeld. Core Data was having trouble finding my model so was displaying this error. Hope it helps somebody someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the call stack in your screenshot. It says your `managedObjectModel` method sent `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]`, and *that* called `initFileURLWithPath:`. So, find the point where you sent `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]` and fix your argument to that message.

The argument you passed being invalid suggests that either you passed `nil` for the path (perhaps you tried to find the file in your bundle but it isn't there or has a different name than you looked for), or you passed a pointer to an object that isn't a string (perhaps you had a string but under-retained it and a different object was created in its place).

Comment: Thanks Peter you've become my savior... By your comments I realized that my unit test target was having trouble finding my data model. I had previously added .xcdatamodel file to the unit test target, so I removed it & added the root file .xcdatamodeld & now unit tests started working normally...

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in some version(s) of the SDK that broke exception handling in the simulator.

Can you run the tests on a device?

Comment: I have a iPhone 3G but I havent upgraded it to iOS 4.x.. So running on device is not currently possible... & my provisioning profiles are outdated...